# Leaflet build polygon from data from MYSQL

Tags: leaflet

Good evening I'm trying to build a polygon with some data taken from a select in my MYSQL DB, the result is that I don't see the polygon but the points.
if I enter the coordinates manually it works by building the polygon, if I use the variables of my selection the db shows me only the points corresponding to the coordinates.
I hope I was clear (I attach code)

```
$sql = "SELECT `LAT`,`LONG` FROM `dati`WHERE `AREA` LIKE '%001%'"; 
 $result = $conn->query($sql);  // while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

// Creating latlng object
var latlngs = [[<?php echo $row["LAT"] ?> ,<?php echo $row["LONG"] ?>,] ];
// Creating a polygon
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'});
// Adding to polygon to map
polygon.addTo(map);

 </script>   
 <?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The points of each polygon are not coming out of the SQL query in the right order. Consider looking at MySQL spatial.

Answer (score 0):

Polygon is an array of points https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polygon . In your code polygon is created by one point.

you should build valid leaflet polygon string, like this

```
$polygonData = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $polygonData[] = sprintf('[%s, %s]', $row["LAT"], $row["LONG"])
}
$polygonData = sprintf('[%s]', implode(',', $polygonData))
```

or some else way to generate such string format

```
[[37, -109.05],[41, -109.03],[41, -102.05],[37, -102.04]]
```

then out of while cycle

```
var latlngs =  <?php echo $polygonData ?>
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'});
polygon.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks ..... I did as you told me and it works fine ... thanks
Now I have to understand what you said to me